# wicked_pdf libssl.so.1.1 cannot open shared object file, no such file or directory

Tags: linux-mint, exit-code, wicked-pdf

I installed my repo on a new machine, and now getting this error during wicked_pdf

```
Rendered user_mailer/base.pdf.erb (3102.9ms)
[wicked_pdf]: ["/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@asdf/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.6/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20231214-4454-xzbi60.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20231214-4454-5amxgz.pdf"]
UserMailer#base_purchase_email: processed outbound mail in 3906.2ms
RuntimeError: Failed to execute:
["/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@asdf/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.6/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20231214-4454-xzbi60.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20231214-4454-5amxgz.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: pid 5257 exit 127
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@asdf/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.6/bin/wkhtmltopdf_ubuntu_18.04_amd64: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

    from app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:287:in `block in base_purchase_email'
    from app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:285:in `base_purchase_email'
    from (irb):3
```

i had difficulty with libssl when installing the repo but I cannot remember the details